# Method that returns nullable that works for reference- as well as value types

Tags: c#, generics, constraints, nullable

I started like that:

```
T? Foo<T>(T obj) //where T : struct
{
    return Random.Shared.Next() < 100 ? (T?)null : (T?)obj;
}
```

which leads to this error:

> Cannot convert null to 'type' because it is a non-nullable value type

Then I added a struct contraint and it worked:

```
T? Foo<T>(T obj) where T : struct
{
    return Random.Shared.Next() < 100 ? null : obj;
}
```

But since I also need this functionality with reference types I added:

```
T? Foo<T>(T obj) where T : class
{
    return Random.Shared.Next() < 100 ? null : obj;
}
```

But this make the compiler says that "Type 'class' already defines a member called 'member' with the same parameter types". How can I resolve this problem without having to give such methods always different names such as FooValueType and FooReferenceType?

Comment: What about the `where T : notnull` constraint?

Comment: This doesn't help since as you already argued, it is just a metadata annotation which does not make the signature unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot really resolve this. The two cases cannot be the same overload because the meaning of the return parameter type `T?` is too different in the two cases (it means `System.Nullable<T>` in the `struct` (value type) case, and just `T` with some metadata annotations in the `class` (reference type) case).

And as you have discovered, two overloads (methods with identical names) are not allowed to differ at constraint only.

One way you could work around it is by introducing a formal unused parameter that you can make optional, in one of the overloads. Then you have:

```cs
T? Foo<T>(T obj) where T : struct
{
    return Random.Shared.Next() < 100 ? null : obj;
}

T? Foo<T>(T obj, bool dummy = false) where T : class
{
    return Random.Shared.Next() < 100 ? null : obj;
}
```

---

**Later addition:** I came to think of another way (hack) you could try. You could let one of the overloads take the argument by read-only reference with the modifier `in`, and the other use a standard by value approach. So:

```cs
T? Foo<T>(in T obj) where T : struct
{
    return Random.Shared.Next() < 100 ? null : obj;
}

T? Foo<T>(T obj) where T : class
{
    return Random.Shared.Next() < 100 ? null : obj;
}
```

Of course this means `obj` is readonly in the body of one overload (but not in the other), but that is probably not an issue (in principle, it may even boost your performance if you use huge structs).

Comment: although this absolutely makes no sense to me it seems to work..  :) since the compiler is obviously capable to resolve these overloads although the seconds argument is never given, some constraint is forcing us to keep this argument.

Comment: "The two cases cannot be the same overload because the meaning of the return parameter type T? is too different in the two case"

thats inaccurate overloads do NOT care about return...the problem is the two params are the same so the signature is the same.

crazily two nullables isnt the same signature cause one becomes Nullable<T> behind the scenes

```
public static T Do<T>(
       T? t
    ) where T: struct
    {
        ...
    }

    public static T Do<T>(
       T? t
    ) where T : class
    {
        ...
    }
```

is perfectly legal!?